# Is it possible to have always running event loop in ipython similar to how it's done in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, python-asyncio

In Jupyter there is always running event loop which allows you to interactively execute code while having some coroutines running in background (e.g. launched with `asyncio.create_task` ).  Such behavior makes testing concurrent code much easier. Is it possible to somehow achieve same behavior in ipython?

I use python 3.8 and ipython 7.12.

Comment: jupyter console does this, just run `jupyter console` from your terminal and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [aioconsole](https://aioconsole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
Just install it with pip :

```
pip3 install aioconsole
```

You can then run the `apython` command to run the interactive asynchronous python shell in which you can run asynchronous code. Example of usage :

```
$ apython
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
---
This console is running in an asyncio event loop.
It allows you to wait for coroutines using the '{0}' syntax.
Try: await asyncio.sleep(1, result=3)
---
>>> await asyncio.sleep(1, result=3)
3
>>>
```